# iOS Receiving Data From a Server

Tags: ios, text

I am interested in making an app that reads "text" from a file and prints it into a label.

I would receive the data from a server and the label will print that text.

Does anyone have basic websites, documents I should take a look at?

I need to get a starting point. NOT interested in any code for I am doing this as a learning experience. Do you know of a good place to start?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by taking a look at `NSURLConnection`. You can find a basic outline (and code) [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html). There are lots of examples around this if you Google it.

Comment: Thanks. :) Any advice before I start looking into things?

Comment: NP. No specific advice. Just start small (and simple) and don't wait ;)